# Update javascript URL in header - Domain Mapping Plugin

Tags: plugins, multisite, wp-head, domain-mapping

I am seeing the following script being called in my `wp_head();` it is associated with the Domain Mapping plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http:/mywebsite.com/dm-sso-endpoint/1510878861/?dm_action=domainmap-setup-cdsso"></script>
```

I need to update that src to be `https://` based on some research this is a known bug. What I am trying to do is find where this url which I am sure is dybnamically created can be found at.

**What I have done so far:**
I have been inside the Domain Mapping plugin but not sure which file would be responsible for creating this javascript call that happens in the header.

Comment: If you're using WordPress 4.5 or higher, [domain mapping is a native feature](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Multisite_Domain_Mapping). (If you're using WP 4.5 or lower, you should probably consider updating.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the file responsible for building the URL placed in the header:

```
wp-content/plugins/domain-mapping/classes/Domainmap/Module/Cdsso.php
```

I was able to update `line# 391` and statically set the protocol to HTTPS which for my use case works. Obliviously we would want to check if SSL is being forced or if the current URL is https and then set it dynamically. I may work out a fix that includes that and post it.

Comment: Line 391 is a comment on my end, can you show me what is on the line?